# Dash constants and prefixes

Tags: dash

Is there any list of Dash constants available? Something like [Bitcoin list of address prefixes](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  This **[Table](https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-system/wiki/Altcoin-Version-Mappings#bip44-altcoin-version-mapping-table)** will be very useful for techies. The application of version numbers in the referenced table are used to compute prefixes for various private keys for numerous alts.  The file references to the far right of the table should be correct.  However, the line numbers have surely changed during the last 3 years. Then also look at the 1st column of the lower table you referenced.

Here is how the referenced libbitcoin table can be utilized for Dash. Let's assume the DASH secp256k1 private key is one of the worst private keys possible in hexadecimal format is

*0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff*

and its associated hexadecimal compressed public key can be calculated simply with:

`% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public`

*020d47568a5e517067a2836c3823fbc58169a7662bfae934a4d41da3e23c98d816*

**Associated Compressed Wallet Input Format (WIF) Private Key:**

`% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | sed 's/$/01/' | bx base58check-encode -v 204`

*XBHdfdHC4YocfzyfuFRx3DxjmvFJmK3txDh3zXk29GxpMWaWfDKL*

**Associated Wallet Input Format (WIF) Private Key:**

`% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx base58check-encode -v 204`

*7qYrzgwRFrM5TWSyqzeNXs4ZoRka2Rw8EsTHzSYVojawgYVzSH5*

**Associated Compressed Pay to Public Key Hash (P2PKH) Address:**

`% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public | bx ec-to-address -v 76`

*XyHHinPZB5Q4FC9jtbksaQBJmXq48gtVGb*

where: bx ec-to-address -v 76  ==  bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode -v 76

**Associated Uncompressed Pay to Public Key Hash (P2PKH) Address:**

`% echo "0000111122223333444455556666777788889999aaaabbbbccccddddeeeeffff" | bx ec-to-public -u | bx ec-to-address -v 76`

*XwxeKFtAXa9wGvX4QijQxz2yC4hMzfAa13*

**An Associated Simple Pay to Script Hash (P2SH) Address:**

`% echo "[020d47568a5e517067a2836c3823fbc58169a7662bfae934a4d41da3e23c98d816] checksig" | bx script-to-address -v 16`

*7fePc8Mf7RYghdxkSp5yaWfT9WR4F2Dsqa*

where: bx script-to-address -v 16  ==  bx script-encode | bx sha256 | bx ripemd160 | bx base58check-encode -v 16

Answer (score 0):

The version bytes commonly used by [Dash](https://dash-docs.github.io/en/developer-reference#address-conversion) are:

```
   0x4c for P2PKH addresses on the main Dash network (mainnet)
   0x8c for P2PKH addresses on the Dash testing network (testnet)
   0x10 for P2SH addresses on mainnet
   0x13 for P2SH addresses on testnet
```